# Ramadan - UK times - is it even possible?

Tags: ramadan

How is this even possible in the UK? I want to fast but I want to also go to work and do my job. The times for fasting will be from 2:30 am until 9:23pm. I'm a father of two and wake up at 6am most days, so I would get just over four hours sleep. My wife does not work I am concerned I won't be able to perform my job.

How is this possible whilst going to work in the UK?

Comment: Try doing it. Take food with you. If you see yourself performing badly, eat it. However, keep in mind that you need to atone for those days you do eat (fasting 2 consecutive months or feeding 60 people).

Comment: If you can consider [taking a holiday](http://quran.com/4/100) for a [month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawm#Fasting_in_the_Qur.27an) at least, try enjoying the [Falkland Islands](http://www.timeanddate.com/sun/falkland/stanley?month=6&year=2015). A cheap trick, I know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no execuse for giving up the mandatory fasts of Ramadan, with some exceptions which your case does not belong to.

If your thurst and/or hunger is unbearable (which I doubt would happen in a country like UK where they have a moderate weather), such that you feel that if continued it might be dangerous to your health, only then you can break your fast. Even then you have to initiate your fast everyday with the intention of completing it. Will have to then make-up for those broken fasts, after Ramadan.

---

In some locations of the Earth there are even longer fasting hours than this. So your's is still a bit convenient. Imagine the sun not (properly) setting at all.

Answer (score 0):

When is the time of sunrise and sunset in london, I guess it's 4:46 AM and 9:11(got it from google) respectively. Your only way is to take high calorie diet at the sahr time, and have faith in Allah that you won't face any difficulties during your day. May Allah help you

Comment: Time of fast starts before the official sunrise.

Comment: See also: [Are Fajr & Isha the Nautical Twilights?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24964/9123) @BleedingFingers

Answer (score 0):

Allah (swt) created ease in this religion even mandatory fast are an ease. Keeping the remembrance of Allah (swt) also help in that aspect always remember the people before you were tested in much harder trials and they managed through them. If they did so can you.

There is a one exceptions which is permissible to break the fast during Ramadan but you still need to make up for those days lost.

> That the Messenger of Allah fasted during Ramadan and broke his fast
> when traveling.
>
> Grade : Sahih (Darussalam)
>
> Sunan an-Nasa'i 2293

There was a scholarly answer also to which extend it becomes compulsory to do so.

> http://islamqa.info/en/48975

Answer (score 0):

Aww,

You need to change your daily routine. Get your four hours during the night, and go to sleep after work and before iftaar. This is what many people do.

If possible, reduce your hours at work.

I know many people who take the last 10 days of ramadan off for ibaadah. you could do that too.

Remember that Ramadan is a month in which good deeds are multiplied, so we should try our best to do as many good deeds in this month as possible. People are able to change their routines for a new diet, due to health problems, etc. We should be able to do it too, for the month of ramadan, so that we can do more ibaadah and gain more reward.

wwb

Answer (score -3):

God says: يُرِيدُ ٱللَّهُ بِكُمُ ٱلۡيُسۡرَ وَلَا يُرِيدُ بِكُمُ ٱلۡعُسۡرَ

“God wishes for you ease, he does not wish for you difficulty”.

You need to distinguish the letter of the law from the spirit of the law. There is nothing in the Qur’an about when you should begin or end the fast. The hadith and fiqh were made for people living in Arabia and do not take into consideration the needs of people living in northern countries. If you fast for 12 hours you are doing enough. Begin at nine in the morning and fast until sunset. Do not listen to other people, it is between you and your God.

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted, but I am wondering if you could include more information in your answer when you have time. Why do people insist on sunrise to sunfall when this is clearly very hard in many countries.

Comment: This answer is manifestly wrong. The Qur'an clearly states the beginning and end of the fast: " And eat and drink until the white thread of dawn becomes distinct to you from the black thread [of night]. Then complete the fast until the sunset." [2:187](http://quran.com/2/187)

Comment: The mufassirun have debated what is actually meant by الخيط الأبيض 
and  الخيط الأسود من الفجر

Comment: @masfenix the whole point of fasting, no matter how hard it is, is to discipline the body. if one has proper intentions to do the fast for it's reason, then you won't think about it being "too hard" or "too long". kind of defeats the whole purpose of fasting if we're thinking about when sunset arrives, and how hungry we are.

Comment: @aasheq So if there's a debate about something, then it doesn't mean anything at all and everything goes?