# What is the meaning of words "الْخَیْطُ الْأَبْیَضُ" and "الْخَیْطِ الْأَسْوَدِ" in surat 2:187?

Tags: tafseer, quran-translation, surat-al-baqarah

The holy Quran say:

> «...کُلُوا وَ اشْرَبُوا حَتَّى یَتَبَیَّنَ لَکُمُ الْخَیْطُ
>   الْأَبْیَضُ مِنَ الْخَیْطِ الْأَسْوَدِ مِنَ الْفَجْرِ ثُمَّ أَتِمُّوا
>   الصِّیَامَ إِلَى اللَّیْلِ...»
>
> ...And eat and drink until the white thread of dawn becomes distinct
>   to you from the black thread [of night]. Then complete the fast until
>   the sunset....(Surat Al-Baqarah ,verse 187)

Now my question is What is the meaning of this 2 words in this statement:

white thread "الْخَیْطُ الْأَبْیَضُ" of dawn becomes distinct to you from the black thread "الْخَیْطِ الْأَسْوَدِ" [of night] ?

Comment: A bit [controversial](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24671/ramadan-uk-times-is-it-even-possible#comment43066_24675)

Answer (score 3):

The black thread is a symbolic formulation of the darkness of the night (light) and the white thread is a symbolic formulation of the brightness of the day (fajr).

(To be found for example in Mokhtassar Tafsir ibn Kathir)

So once you can make a difference between darkness and brightness you should start your fast.

I found some Ahadith in Sahih Muslim and Sahih al-Bukhary and Sunan abi Dawod which quote this, espacially the Versions narrated by Muslim and abi Dawod support the tafsir above. Here's the one from Sahih Muslim:

> 'Adi b. Hatim (Allah be pleased with him) reported that when (this
>   verse) was revealed: " Until the white streak of the dawn becomes
>   distinct from the dark streak" (2: 187) Adi b. Hatim said: Messenger
>   of Allah, verily I keep underneath my pillow two strings, one white
>   and the other black, by which I distinguish night from dawn. Upon this
>   the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: Your pillow seems to be very large.
>   For the word khait implies the blackness of the night and the
>   whiteness of the dawn.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ
>   بْنُ إِدْرِيسَ، عَنْ حُصَيْنٍ، عَنِ الشَّعْبِيِّ، عَنْ عَدِيِّ بْنِ
>   حَاتِمٍ، - رضى الله عنه - قَالَ لَمَّا نَزَلَتْ ‏{‏ حَتَّى يَتَبَيَّنَ
>   لَكُمُ الْخَيْطُ الأَبْيَضُ مِنَ الْخَيْطِ الأَسْوَدِ مِنَ
>   الْفَجْرِ‏}‏ قَالَ لَهُ عَدِيُّ بْنُ حَاتِمٍ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ
>   إِنِّي أَجْعَلُ تَحْتَ وِسَادَتِي عِقَالَيْنِ عِقَالاً أَبْيَضَ
>   وَعِقَالاً أَسْوَدَ أَعْرِفُ اللَّيْلَ مِنَ النَّهَارِ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ
>   اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ إِنَّ وِسَادَتَكَ لَعَرِيضٌ إِنَّمَا
>   هُوَ سَوَادُ اللَّيْلِ وَبَيَاضُ النَّهَارِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏